# Use Django ORM values and call member functions

Tags: django, django-orm

I have below model in my Django app.

```
class Revenue(models.Model):
    from_a = models.IntegerField()
    from_b = models.IntegerField()

    def get_total(self):
        return self.from_a + self.from_b
```

Now I am retrieving data using `Revenue.objects.filter(from_a__gt = 10).values('from_a', 'from_b')`.

From the above queryset I am getting values, now I want to call `get_total` function on objects.
I didn't found a way to call that function.

Is there a way to retrieve the data only I needed using `values` and also can call `member_functions` of that objects?

`Revenue.objects.filter(from_a__gt = 10)` should not be the solution if I have 100s of columns for my model.

Comment: Well having 100 columns should is not a good idea in general, typically that means something is *rotten* in your design.

Comment: Yeah not exactly 100, I have other columns with textfields which holds large texts. But I want to know is there a way to get the data of columns which I needed and also able to call the functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From the above queryset I am getting values, now I want to call `get_total` function on objects. I didn't found a way to call that function.

Well you obtain a `QuerySet` (that is at that point not evaluated), so a *collection* of `Revenue`s. You can not directly call the function on that collection. But you can *iterate* through the queryset, and call the function on the inidvidual objects. We can for example make a list with:

```
[r.get_total() for r in Revenue.objects.filter(from_a__gt = 10)]
```

> Is there a way to retrieve the data only I needed using values and also can call `member_functions` of that objects?

Yes, you can use the `.only(..)` element on the query, to restrict the number of columns that are loaded:

```
[r.get_total() for r in Revenue.objects.filter(from_a__gt = 10).only('from_a', 'from_b')]
```

This will construct `Revenue` objects, but we will only load the specified columns. In that case we will load only `from_a` and `from_b`, and if you later need *other* fields, these will be loaded with *extra* queries.

In case however the logic in the `member_function`s is easy, you better use *annotations*: these are then processed in the database, and thus allow filtering. This is however not always possible: Python allows to calculate very complicated things that would result in a gigantic equivalent SQL expression. Furthermore most databases do not allow to contact webservices and file systems, so some functions are fundamentally impossible to translate in an annotation.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing this on model level you can use [`F expression`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations) with your query:

```
from django.db.models import F

Revenue.objects.filter(from_a__gt = 10).annotate(
    get_total=F('from_a') + F('from_b')
).values('from_a', 'from_b', 'get_total')
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends in what you want to do... if you want `get_total` shows as field, you can make this method one property method, he will be calculated field, so its not persist in data base

**Property Method**

```
@property
def get_total(self):
    return self.from_a + self.from_b

Revenue.objects.filter(from_a__gt = 10).values('from_a', 'from_b', 'get_total')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods

You can call it like regular class method, so when you get the model instance you can call it

```
revenues = Revenue.objects.filter(from_a__gt = 10).values('from_a', 'from_b')
for revenue in revenues:
    print(revenue.get_total)

# OR
[r.get_total for r in Revenue.objects.filter(from_a__gt = 10)] # Like Wilem Van said
```

**Static Method**

Using it as static method (this way isnt the best fit for your need but is nice to know), you will bind this method with the class, so you dont need one object instance to manage it, just the class reference
class Revenue(...):
...

```
    @staticmethod
    def get_total(valueA, valueB):
        return valueA + valueB
```

To call it is like that
Revenue.get_total(5, 10)

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/staticmethod

Obs.: Weird, didnt got one good referente to staticmethod at django docs

Comment: Referring to your first example, How can an model instance method i.e. "get_total" work in .values() method of the Queryset?

Comment: I realized i wrote some mistakes in there, so now is updated, the method will be handled as regular field inside your class, so that is not persisted is calculated by the time you instantiate it, so you can use values() and define which columns you want to be shown in your queryset like (class attrA, attrB, @property attrC (return attrA+attrC) MyClass.objects.all().values('attrA', 'attrB', attrC')